# Reverse a list with foldr and foldl using the same auxiliary functions

Tags: list, scheme, reverse, fold

```
1. (define (rev1 ls) (foldr g '() (map f ls))) 
2. (define (rev2 ls) (foldl g '() (map f ls)))
```

I need to define `f` and `g` such that both `rev1` and `rev2` produce the reverse of the given list `ls`, where other definition are as follows

```
(define (foldl op z ls) 
   (if (null? ls) 
       z 
       (foldl op (op z (car ls)) (cdr ls))))

(define (snoc x y) (cons y x))

(define (foldr op z ls)
     (if (null? ls)
        z
        (op (car ls) (foldr op z (cdr ls)))))
```

I am not sure how to define `f` and `g` in such way that both 1 and 2 produce the reverse of the argument list.

Comment: The way your question is formatted at the moment doesn't fit with stack overflow rules and will likely attract a large number of down votes or be closed very quickly. To avoid this, it's a good idea to edit your question to provide clear examples of your overall problem, what issues you're facing, what you have tried, and why those don't work. Also, it's worth searching to see if your question has already been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather contrived exercise, but anyway - these procedures should work:

```
(define f list)

(define (g e acc)
  (append acc e))
```

For example:

```
(rev1 '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(5 4 3 2 1)

(rev2 '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(5 4 3 2 1)
```

Comment: `(define (g a b) (append b a))` is enough. `(list? acc)` always returns `#t`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. You can attack it with recursive thinking and equational reasoning (substituting equals for equals, in the code).

First, re-write:

```
(rev1 ls) 
 = (letrec ( (rev1 (lambda (ls)
                     (foldr g '() (map f ls)) )) ) 
     (rev1 ls))

 = (letrec ( (rev1 (lambda (ls)
                     (foldr g '() (map f ls)) )) ) 
     (foldr g '() (map f ls)))

 = (letrec ( (rev1  (lambda (ls)
                      (foldr g '() (map f ls)) )) 
             (foldr (lambda (op z ls)
                     (if (null? ls)
                       z
                       (op (car ls) (foldr op z (cdr ls)))) )) ) 
     (foldr g '() (map f ls)))

 = (letrec ( (foldr (lambda (op z ls)
                     (if (null? ls)
                       z
                       (op (car ls) (foldr op z (cdr ls)))) ))
             (rev11 (lambda (ls)
                      (if (null? ls)
                        '()
                        (g (f (car ls)) (foldr g '() (map f (cdr ls))))) )) ) 
     (rev11 ls))

 = (letrec ( (rev11 (lambda (ls)
                      (if (null? ls)
                        '()
                        (g (f (car ls)) (rev11 (cdr ls)))) )) ) 
     (rev11 ls))
```

because `(map f (cons x xs)) == (cons (f x) (map f xs))`.

Similarly,

```
(rev2 ls)
 = (letrec ( (rev2 (lambda (ls)
                     (foldl g '() (map f ls)) )) )
     (rev2 ls))

 = (letrec ( (rev2  (lambda (ls)
                      (foldl g '() (map f ls)) ))
             (foldl (lambda (op z ls) 
                      (if (null? ls) 
                        z 
                        (foldl op (op z (car ls)) (cdr ls))) )) )
     (foldl g '() (map f ls)))

 = (letrec ( (rev22 (lambda (z ls) 
                      (if (null? ls) 
                        z 
                        (rev22 (g z (f (car ls))) (cdr ls))) )) )
     (rev22 '() ls))
```

(do complete the missing steps in the second derivation).

Thus we've derived the new definitions

```
(define (rev11 ls)    (if (null? ls)    ; (rev1 ls) == (rev11 ls)
                        '()
                        (g (f (car ls)) (rev11 (cdr ls)))) )

(define (rev22 z ls)  (if (null? ls)    ; (rev2 ls) == (rev22 '() ls)
                        z 
                        (rev22 (g z (f (car ls))) (cdr ls))) )
```

Now we can apply some recursive thinking. Just assume that `rev11` does what it's supposed to do – reverses the list it is given. Thus, for a list `ls == [a,b,c,...,n]`,

```
(rev1 ls)
  = (rev11 ls)
  = (rev11 [a,b,c,...,n])
  = (g (f a) (rev11 [b,c,...,n]))
  = (g (f a) [n,...,c,b])    ; by assumption
  ; must be equal to
  = [n,...,c,b,a]
```

How are we to combine `a` and a list `xs` to get a new one, same as `xs` with `a` at its end?

```
  = (append [n,...,c,b] (list a))
```

Thus `f == list` and `(g x y) == (append y x)`. We've arrived at the definitions seen in [Óscar López's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32448284/849891)!

Now we must see what's going on with `rev22`. If its `f` and `g` will be different, it'll mean that the original question has no solution.

```
(rev2 ls)
= (rev22 '() ls)
= (rev22 '() [a,b,c,...,n])
= (rev22 (g '() (f a)) [b,c,...,n])
= (rev22 (g (g '() (f a)) (f b)) [c,...,n])
= ...
```

As is readily seen, the same `f` and `g` do work here as well.

Noncoincidentally, `rev22` is equivalent to [`append-reverse`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-1.html?q=rev-append#append-reverse), or [Common Lisp's `revappend`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_revapp.htm), with the flipped arguments order.

Another, more *pseudocodey* way of writing the two definitions, with `[]` standing for `'()`, `{x}` for `(f x)` and `x + y` for `(g x y)`, is

```
(rev1 [a,b,...,n]) = {a} + ({b} + ({c} + (... + ({n} + [])...)))
                   = {a} + (rev1 [b,...,n])

(rev2 [a,...,m,n]) = (...((([] + {a}) + {b}) + {c}) + ...) + {n}
                   = (rev2 [a,...,m]) + {n}
```

and now the solution seems almost self-evident!

Note that your `foldl` definition uses [Haskell's](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl) order of arguments to the `g` operator. [In Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=foldl#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) the order is flipped – `z` comes as the *last* argument, not *first*. Consequently, the equations would become

```
(rev1 [a,b,...,n]) = {a} + (rev1 [b,...,n])
(rev2 [a,...,m,n]) = {n} + (rev2 [a,...,m])
```

and for the second equation `+ == g == append` without flipping the arguments order. Then the modified puzzle seems to be impossible to solve.